# How can I check if an Apport report does not contain any sensitive information?

Tags: security, apport

I know the crash reports are stored at `/var/crash`. But can I do something to check that the report does not contain any sensitive information?

Where can I find the list of reports that I or other users have sent using Apport?

Also how secure and privacy respecting is Apport in general? E.g. if I send a report about Ubunutu Software Center is it possible that it might contain my user password or my gmail password I entered in my browser? If yes, which typical user would in her right mind send an Apport report to Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Two already answered questions-answers combined, can solve your query.

First : [Should I include logs that contain "sensitive information"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250097/should-i-include-logs-that-contain-sensitive-information?rq=1)

Second: [Why did Apport make my bug report private?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16135/why-did-apport-make-my-bug-report-private)

If you want to examine the files by your self (in `/var/crash`) you can do it as well. You can use `less` pager for example

```
less /var/crash/someprog.crash
```